# Removing Selected Option From Database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a select element created dynamically with items from my database. I would like to be able to delete the record from the database if the delete button is selected. Currently I have an AJAX function that is sending a GET request to my current page to remove it, and it removes the item from my options, however, my PHP used to access my database is never called and therefore when I refresh, the query is ran and what I just "removed" is displayed again because it is still in my db. I know I must be missing something simplistic, I just can't quite put my 
finger on it and would appreciate any help or advice. I'm open to other methods as well. This is definitely not my strong suit.

My AJAX:

```
     window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("deleteLoc").onclick = function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "adminLocationEdit.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        data:{deleteLoc : $("#lList option:selected").val() },
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        });
       $("#lList option:selected").remove();
        }
    };
```

My HTML:

```
    <select id ="lList" multiple="multiple" style="width:400px;height:400px;">  
    <?php   
    //Query that selects all locations from the database and creates the list dynamically.
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM location";
    $qry_result = odbc_exec($admconn,$qry) or die("A database error has been detected. Err: adminLocationListEdit-1");

    //Echo the db results into the select box.
    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($qry_result)){
    //Sets each row to variable. 
    $locID = $row['locationName'];
    echo "<option id =\"$locID\" name = \"$locID\" onclick =\"$('#form1').load('incl/adminLocationEdit.php?loc='+$(this).attr('id'));displayFieldsets('form1', 'locList', 'lList');\">" . $locID . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

My PHP:

```
//If user wants to add a new location
if(isset($_POST['addLoc'])){
    //Re-directs
    //header("Location: adminLocation.php");
    exit;  

}
//If user wants to Delete a location from the database.
if(isset($_POST['deleteLoc'])){
    $contentToDelete = $_POST['deleteLoc']; 
    //Deletes current location from the database.
    $qry = "DELETE FROM location WHERE locationName = '" . $contentToDelete . "'";
    $qry_result = odbc_exec($admconn,$qry) or die("A database error has been detected. Err: adminLocationListEdit-2");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing both `GET` and `POST`

If you are looking for post,

This should be

```
data:{deleteLoc : $("#lList option:selected").val() },
```

Or if you are looking fr `GET`

```
type: "GET",// this should be GET not POST
```

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I've edited my code in my question now to represent what I have, it is still not working as anticipated. I've never used Ajax before so I really don't understand how it work completely yet so I'm uncertain if that is correct.

Comment: I was calling the wrong page from my includes. Thank you so much for your help and critique. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Glad i could help you:)